# Need help with exiting full-screen mode in Code editor on Elementary OS

Tags: elementary-os, fullscreen

I am having trouble getting the Code editor to exit full-screen mode on my Elementary OS system. I have tried using the Windows key together with <kbd>down arrow</kbd>, and also <kbd>F11</kbd>, but neither method works. I also attempted to adjust the Window Controls in Settings, but this did not solve the issue.

Do you have any suggestions for how I can exit full-screen mode?

Comment: What is the code editor that you are using? Visual Studio Code?